# date parameter similar to access in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am working on a query that we are expanding from a more simple query in MS Access.  In the Access query there is a date value of `REQUIREMENTS_DATE < Now()-([M: 56 T:57 W:58 Th: 59 F:60])` where I have `REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - 60` below.  The access query allows the person running the report to enter a given number of days based on the day of the week it is but as of now, I have to manually change the SQL code which isn't a big deal for me but I would like to export this to Excel and have something a user with little SQL knowledge could execute.  Is there anything similar in SQL server to the function being used in Access so that my user could enter a value and have the report ran for that date:

```
SELECT                  P.PLANT_CODE,
                P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P.PERIOD_CODE,
                P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P.PLANNED_QTY AS 'REM PLAN QTY',
                P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.PLANNED_QTY + P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'ORIGINAL FCST QTY'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.PLANT_CODE IN ('6040','6041')
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 AND            P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00','01','ZU','Z2')
 AND            P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - 60
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY
```

Comment: Is there any way to add something in SQL Server that would act the same as the Access function - changing the GATEDATE() based on the day of the week.

Comment: Are you familiar with `datepart()` and the `case` statement?

Comment: I have briefly went over the case statements in my last course but I am not to familiar with how they would be applied or the best place in the query for them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this:

```
declare @number as int
set @number =   CASE
                WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Monday'
                THEN 56
                WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday'
                THEN 57
                WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Wednesday'
                THEN 58
                WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Thursday'
                THEN 59
                WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Friday'
                THEN 60
                END;


SELECT          P.PLANT_CODE,
                P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P.PERIOD_CODE,
                P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P.PLANNED_QTY AS 'REM PLAN QTY',
                P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.PLANNED_QTY + P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'ORIGINAL FCST QTY'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.PLANT_CODE IN ('6040','6041')
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 AND            P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00','01','ZU','Z2')
 AND            P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - @number
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly - thank you so much. I was wondering, could I have used DATEPART instead of DATENAME and then used = 1,2,3, etc? instead of the name of the day?  Either way this worked well and I actually learned something!

Comment: I have no idea why you would add an additional variable, when you can just put the `case` statement directly into the query.

Comment: I was curious about that - how would you insert the CASE statment, can it be in the WHERE clause?

Comment: You would just insert the `CASE` block into the spot currently occupied by `@number`. I just wrote it as a variable to make the query easier to digest. You can do whatever you want.